# Drawing objects less than 1 pixel (Graphics2D/Java)

Tags: java, swing, drawing, zooming, graphics2d

I draw lots of dots on the Swing(Jpanel).
I make that panel zoomable, zoom-in works fine, but I have a problem at zoom-out when it was zoomed-out to the limit, I draw dots per pixel.
I want to zoom-out it more, how can I draw it on `Graphics2D`
And those dots on the panel are editable(by using a mouse). Since they are drawn less than one pixel, how can I get their actually drawn position?

Comment: [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I read it, but
 I have no idea how can I implement it.

Comment: I had to manually compensate for the zoom.  So if the object will end up smaller than one pixel, just take it's base size and divide by the zoom factor.  This will make it 'larger' in un-zoomed pixels, and thus zoom down to no more than one pixel.  Same with any size that you want to limit, either up or down.